# How to stop a service if it is running using Ansible

Tags: jenkins, ansible, devops, ansible-2.x

I would like to know the best way to stop a service in Ansible only if the service is running. I wish to do something along these lines

```
- name: Check to see if Jenkins is running
  service:
    name: jenkins
    state: status
  register: jenkins_running_status

- name: Stop Jenkins if it is running
  service:
    name: jenkins
    state: stopped
  when: jenkins_running_status == False
```

Obviously this does not work. I would like to know the best way to stop a service like Jenkins if only it is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to check if service is running. If it's running, ansible will stop it, if it's not, nothing will happen, as state is already stopped.

So something like this should be enough for what you need.

```
- name: Stop Jenkins
  service:
    name: jenkins
    state: stopped
```

However, to answer your question, something like this will work (I assume you use systemd):

```
- name: Check Jenkins
  shell: systemctl status jenkins.service | grep Active | awk -v N=2 '{print $N}'
  register: output

- name: Stop Jenkins
  service:
    name: jenkins
    state: stopped
  when: output.stdout == 'active'
```